# JSON spreadsheet into JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, database, data-visualization

I have just taken a module on data visualization this semester and I am supposed to be turning Google Spreadsheets into JSON using jQuery.

I have a spreadsheet with two simple columns: `date` and `status` (it was data collected on myself for the purpose of learning how to visualize it).

Now, what I want to do is to get the data from the spreadsheet, which I was able to do this way:

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Zw0M9zbepK0ML3mWIQQ6r8CPVzPPdxlNbJKTBqF-2vA/1/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
  //first row "title" column
  console.log(data.feed.entry[0]['content']['$t']);
});
```

However, I can't visualize the data by putting it into an HTML element like a `div` or `table`, regardless of the different ways I am trying. I am sure that I'm not doing something correctly or that I just lack the knowledge to do it (I'm only a rookie at data visualization). I would really appreciate any suggestions from you :) Thank you!

-D

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid toolkit like Kendo.

The Javascript version is open-source and very good at representing the type of data you're consuming into neat grids.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index